# CASE is not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write if..else condition inside sql what I want to get the company name from "Company" table if their are companyID in companyID is NULL  print "N/A" con someone help me

```
SELECT [contactID]
      ,[customerID]
      ,(SELECT Label.labelContactType FROM  Label WHERE Label.labelContactTypeID = Customer_Contacts.labelContactTypeID)AS Type
      ,[contactDetails]
      ,[status]
      ,[notes]
      ,CASE WHEN [Customer_Contacts].companyID = NULL THEN 'N/A'
        WHEN [Customer_Contacts].companyID  <> NULL THEN (SELECT [companyName]
        FROM [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Company] WHERE [Company].companyID = [Customer_Contacts].companyID)
        END AS Company

  FROM [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Customer_Contacts]

  WHERE customerID = 24
```

Comment: Define "not working". Does that mean errors? Does it mean wrong results (in which case, explain what results you do get and what you expect). This question, as it currently stands cannot be answered with more detail from yourself.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You should really rewrite this query using JOINs

Comment: `SELECT NULL = NULL` vs `SELECT NULL IS NULL`

Comment: @cory is right, correlated subqueries are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: CASE is working as expected - the same way as in all RDBMS and in accordance with standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use a `JOIN` for this query:

```
SELECT cc.[contactID]
    ,cc.[customerID]
    ,l.labelContactType AS Type
    ,cc.[contactDetails]
    ,cc.[status]
    ,cc.[notes]
    , COALESCE(cp.[companyName], 'N/A') AS Company
FROM [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Customer_Contacts] cc
LEFT JOIN [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Company] cp
    on cc.companyID = cp.companyID
LEFT JOIN Label l
    on cc.labelContactTypeID = l.labelContactTypeID
WHERE cc.customerID = 24
```

If you need help with join syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 8):

Try using 'IS NULL' instead of '= NULL', and 'IS NOT NULL' instead of '<> NULL'.

Answer (score 1):

I would really rewrite this using `JOIN`s: it is more readable, maintainable, and will be more efficient. What you are currently doing is implementing correlated subqueries (two of them; one for the label, one for the company name). Here is your query rewritten with `JOIN`s and reformatted for readability:

```
SELECT 
    cust.[contactID]
    ,cust.[customerID]
    ,l.labelContactType AS Type
    ,cust.[contactDetails]
    ,cust.[status]
    ,cust.[notes]
    ,ISNULL(comp.companyName, 'N/A') AS Company
FROM 
    [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Customer_Contacts] cust
LEFT JOIN
    [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Label] l
    ON
    cust.labelContactTypeID = l.labelContactTypeID
LEFT JOIN
    [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Company] comp
    ON
    cust.companyID = comp.companyID
WHERE 
    cust.customerID = 24
```

I would research the `JOIN` syntax if you are unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you mean by 'not working'. It is important to say exactly what you mean by 'not working' - returns incorrect results? Throws an error?

In this case, I believe that the problem is that you are testing NULL with '=' and ANSI_NULLS is ON. If you are getting a message like 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'' and 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'', then I think this is your problem.

If that is the case, you can do a couple of things. 1. Turn `ANSI_NULLS OFF`. I don't recommend this. 2. Change = `NULL` to `IS NULL` and `<> NULL` to `IS NOT NULL`. This is the approach I recommend.

Answer (score 0):

When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is ON (default and standard setting) you need to compare columns with NULL using `a_column IS NULL` or `a_column IS NOT NULL` construct.

When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is OFF, the Equals (`=`) and Not Equal To (`<>`) works - but it is nonstandard. I recommend do not alter default setting of ANSI_NULL.